# How to replace <iframe> youtube link to using Regex in Yahoo pipe

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

Most of Youtube video included to the website using  tag,
Is there any way to convert such iframe:

```
<iframe height="360" frameborder="0" width="640" src="www.youtube.com/embed/Xz3zC0axQwA?feature=player_detailpage" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

to finally look only like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/Xz3zC0axQwA
```

I would like to use Regex + Yahoo pipe

Comment: Just in case I'm missing something, you **know**every link you're trying to grab will begin with `www.youtube.com/embed/` and then end with `?` after the movie number - That should be a very easy Regex to write... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

RegEx: `(?:<iframe.+src=")([^"]+)(?:.*>)`

Then you'll have a captured group `$1` containing only the `src` url.

Comment: Would you please explain what should I replace, example: Replace this XXX to this XXXX

Comment: Match the above RegEx then replace it with capture group #1.